# Too many calendar or calendar entries has been created within short time

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Calendar Apps script

Script said to me: Too many calendar or calendar entries has been created within short time. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) you have certain daily quotas for actions.

```
+-------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|         Feature         | Consumer (gmail.com) | Google Apps for Your Domain | Google Apps for Biz/Edu/Gov |
+-------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Calendar events created | 5,000 / day          | 10,000 / day                | 10,000 / day                |
+-------------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I don't know what you should do to circumvent these limitations. That depends on your requirements. But these look like reasonable quotas. If you need more than this, you might want to rethink your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

 I do not know why it does not work then, because the script wanted to create only 200-300 calendar entries. So I do not understand why I get this error message.